# php regular expression for validating password with wild characters

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I am trying to add wild characters to my current alphanumeric only regular expression to make the password validation stronger. I am not trying to require the user to enter wild characters, just allowing them to enter wild characters.

```
'/^[a-z0-9]{8,16}$/i'
```

I am also using cakephp and doing the validation in the model if that helps, but not really needed for this answer.

```
            'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9]{8,16}$/i',
            'on' => 'create',
            'allowEmpty' => true
```

Comment: What are wild characters? If you want to allow any characters, just use `^.{8,16}$`.

Comment: Do you mean *valid* characters?

Comment: This is for a japanese site and I don't want them putting in japanese characters and other weird characters.

Comment: Ya, I guess valid characters like !#$%&* etc

Comment: Why no japanese characters? Its their passwords, after all.

Comment: Jens, true in that case wouldn't need any validation. But, that is just a requirement from the client.

Comment: Jason, then your client needs to be educated why it is stupid to impose complexity restrictions on passwords. Complexity requirements yes, but why make passwords deliberately *less* secure?

Comment: But the passwords will be saved as a hash in the database, so basically noone will have an idea what kind of passwords are there... right?

Comment: actually you cannot really type a japanese password into a password type input, so you cannot have a japanese password. you can only copy and paste it, so that just complicates things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the characters you want to allow to the character class (`[...]`):

```
/^[a-z0-9!#$%&]{8,16}$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it totally wrong.
never use regexp for password fields. this way you dont allow the user anything, you are just disallowing the user to enter whatever he wants to use as password (maybe some special chars like & or { or whatever.

in any case your approach hurts more than it helps.

what you should do, is encouraging the user to use specialchars and more complex passwords simply by displaying a "red-yellow-green" indicator besides the password field.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you should allow "everything", thus remove the validation on content, and only forbid "empty" strings, or too short strings (ideally with a live javascript validation as an indicator so that people don't have to try 10 times before figuring out what works).

You shouldn't care what people type in, even in Japanese, as you are going to encode this string anyway (I hope!), using CakePHP's built in function, with sha1 and md5 and salt, and you'll end up with something harmless in the end.

Use `$this->Auth->password($string);`